# Optimal portfolio weight derivation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, systems-of-equations, finance, nonlinear-system

I cannot see how to derive the following optimal portfolio weight $w^*$:

$$
w^*
=
\frac
{(b - \frac{1}{2}) \rho \sigma_1\sigma_2 - b\sigma_2^2 +\sigma_1\sigma_2\sqrt{(b - \frac{1}{2})^2\rho^2 + b(1-b)}}
{(1-b)\sigma_1^2 - b\sigma_2^2 + 2(b - \frac{1}{2})\rho\sigma_1\sigma_2}
$$

From this system of equations:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
b \\
1-b \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\frac{1}{\sigma(x)}
\cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
w^2\sigma_1^2 + \rho w(1-w) \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \\
(1-w)^2\sigma_2^2 + \rho w(1-w) \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Where:

$$
\sigma(x) = \sqrt{w^2\sigma_1^2 + (1-w)^2\sigma_2^2 + 2 \rho w(1-w) \sigma_1\sigma_2}
$$

The result is from a finance book called *Introduction to Risk Parity and Budgeting* (2013) by Thierry Roncalli. The derivation is omitted in the text and I can't seem to do it myself, and I cannot find a derivation for this particular case anywhere.

Any advice on how to solve the system would be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by reducing it to the form of a single quadratic equation in $w$.

Eliminate the expression $\sigma(x)$  from the equation   relating the column vectors by looking at the quotient of top and bottom column entries. The quotient you  obtain is

$\frac{1-b}{b}=\frac {(1- w)^2 \sigma_2^2+ \rho \sigma_1 \sigma_2 w(1-w)}{w^2 \sigma_1^2 + w(1-w)\rho \sigma_1 \sigma_2 }$

Then clear of denominators by cross-multiplying to obtain a quadratic equation that $w$ must satisfy.  After expanding out everything in powers of $w$ you get a
quadratic that has the form $Aw^2 + B w+ C=0$.

Explicitly the individual terms in the quadratic have this structure:

$$Aw^2=w^2 [( 2 b-1) \rho  \sigma _2 \sigma _1 +(1-b) \sigma _1^2-b \sigma_2^2]$$

$$Bw= w \left(-2 b \rho  \sigma _1 \sigma _2+2 b
   \sigma _2^2+\rho  \sigma _1 \sigma _2\right)= w ((1-2 b )\rho  \sigma _1 \sigma _2+2 b
   \sigma _2^2)$$

$$C= -b \sigma _2^2$$

The solutions to the quadratic are  $w = \frac{-B/2 \pm \sqrt{ (B/2)^2-  AC}}{A}$.

Note that the denominator term $A$ matches that in the textbook.
Perhaps these pointers will allow you to wrap up the algebra to check also that the numerators agree.

Comment: Why can we use the reduced form of the quadratic formula in this case? We need to know B is an even integer for that right ?
$w = \frac{-B/2 \pm \sqrt{ (B/2)^2-  AC}}{A}$.

Comment: No quadratic formula is valid for all real  (and even complex) numbers A,B,C.

Comment: I mean the reduced form: $w = \frac{-B/2 \pm \sqrt{ (B/2)^2-  AC}}{A}$. 
Not the general form: $w = \frac{-B \pm \sqrt{ B^2-  4AC}}{2A}$. We need B to be an even integer to use the reduced form, right ?

Comment: Nope.Test it out with a calculator and convince yourself it always works.